# How do we log the property name and values?

Tags: arrays, dart

How do we log the property name and values in Dart? e.g "population: 14.35e6"

```
var shanghai = {
  population: 14.35e6,
  longitude: '31.2000 N',
  latitude: '121.5000 E',
  country: 'CHN'
};
for(var key in shanghai){ console.log(key, ": " , shanghai[key]); }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to make some small changes to your code to get it working in Dart. First you have to use strings as keys in your map literal (an alternative would be using symbols). Iterating over the keys of a map is done using the `keys` property. Last, the [`log`](https://api.dartlang.org/133468/dart-html/Console-class.html#log) function does only take one argument in Dart, but you can use [string interpolation](http://shailen.github.io/blog/2012/11/14/dart-string-interpolation/) to combine the key and value to a string.

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var shanghai = {
    "population": 14.35e6,
    "longitude": '31.2000 N',
    "latitude": '121.5000 E',
    "country": 'CHN'
  };

  for(var key in shanghai.keys) { 
    window.console.log("$key: ${shanghai[key]}");    
  }
}
```

If you want to access both keys and values at the same time, you can also use the [`forEach`](https://api.dartlang.org/133591/dart-core/Map-class.html#forEach) function:

```
shanghai.forEach((key, value) => window.console.log("$key: $value"));
```